# How do I fix this unrecognized selector sent to instance error?

Tags: swift, function, button, swift3

Over the past two hours I have been trying to fix something that should be fairly easy. I have 6 buttons on my viewcontroller and I want to change the image when they are tapped. If they are tapped again the image should change back to the original image (selected/deselect idea). However, I cant seem to figure it out and whenever I use my code below it crashes and states:

**CharacteristicsViewController buttonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12dd07390**

Can someone please explain to me how i can change the images of the buttons when tapped?

*PS: In the below code I only connected 1 button to test if I can make it work.*

```
import UIKit

class CharacteristicsViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var confidenceButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    confidenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "confidentnor"), for:   UIControlState.normal)
    confidenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "confidenthigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    confidenceButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonTapped:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    }

func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton)
{
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}

}
```

Comment: Your buttonTapped() function is nested inside viewDidLoad(). Move it out and the error will disappear.

Comment: @dfd I moved the buttonTapped() function outside the viewDidLoad(). And the error still shows up and the app keeps crashing.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is ok, the selector is correctly setup.

The error is saying that the button can't find the method that the selector indicated in the class, particularly the `buttonTapped` method.

The problem is that method is nested inside the viewDidLoad. Move it outside, to the class, and it should work!

try by setting the button target like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testFunc), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func buttonTapped()
{
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
}
```

Comment: I moved it to the class but it keeps on crashing?

Comment: Please someone help me out I am stuck...Why does it keep crashing

Comment: try by setting the button target like this:

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testFunc), for: .touchUpInside)

    func buttonTapped()
    {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
    }

I'll edit the answer for better understanding

Comment: You sir are a genius thank you!!! finally i can continue!